# Tradeoff - Performance vs Space - Boolean vs String Comparison

Tags: c#, performance, database-design, storage

I'm having a use case to display a modal popup only if there is a content to be shown. Content is configurable in the portal.

1. Check if content is not empty and then render the modal popup code
   Cons - **Performance is low : String check is costly**
2. Introduce a new bit column and make it configurable in the portal to
   indicate if modal popup needs to be shown.
   Cons - **More space : Additional column to store the value**

Which approach will you recommend and why?

Comment: Why a `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is costly? You have to provide more information. Anyway this is a subjective question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't think it is truly subjective. I think we can prove that the cost of checking `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is essentially a no-op, which in turn means that it is absolutely the right choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premise of your question is incorrect.

Checking for `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is actually a very cheap operation, with the following source:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty([NotNullWhen(false)] string? value)
{
    if ((object)value != null)
    {
        return value!.Length == 0;
    }
    return true;
}
```

We can prove that this is a quick operation with the following benchmark:

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[ShortRunJob]
public class IsNullOrEmptyBenchmark
{
    private const string Input = "here is an input";

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public bool IsNulLOrEmptyBenchmark()
    {
        var isNullOrEmpty = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            isNullOrEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input);
        }

        return isNullOrEmpty;
    }
}
```

On my machine, this 1000 iteration benchmark (with subsequent assignment) takes a mere 338 ns (a 3rd of an nanosecond per operation, which is essentially a no-op),

[image]

and most likely is dwarfed by the cost of having to maintain additional data. In addition, whatever code is going to execute the modal will be significantly more expensive than this check.

Answer (score 2):

For #1 you're not checking the string on the client side, you're doing it on the server in the query (`len(col) > 0`).

For #2 you're duplicating data, which is not only space inefficient, but a very clear failure point.

That said, if all you're doing is displaying a modal dialog, that means you cannot do it too often to begin with. Optimizing this is a waste of your time (though good design in general isn't, and #2 is the very definition of bad RDMBS design).